Profitability on Value at Risk forecasting
I'm conducting a research related to Value at Risk forecasting using volatility models like GARCH and others. My predictions are turning out quite well with some models. Is there a way to capitalize on these predictions? For example, a trading strategy that utilizes VaR prediction as input, so my profitability depends on how accurate my VaR prediction is? Perhaps with options? Thanks!

Buy a call spread at strike equal to VaR if it's valued at less than your confidence (say 99%). This will get a payout everytime there is a VaR breach, and on average should be profitable. This is though very optimistic.

thanks for answering

Sure thing. Please mark it as the answer, I have formally answered it.

done, thanks again!

Buy a call spread at strike equal to VaR if it's valued at less than your confidence (say 99%). This will get a payout everytime there is a VaR breach, and on average should be profitable. This is though very optimistic.
